# Tables in specific locations

Tags: tables

I'm trying to put tables in specific locations in my text. My supervisor said I can put tables into some sort of equations so that they are no longer floats, however I'm not really sure what he meant. For example, part of my code is as follows.

```
    \begin{table}[H]
\begin{center}
\caption{\label{tab:IPF1} The observed number of counts of the infant survival data}
\begin{tabular}{@{} llcc @{}}
\toprule
& & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Survival}\\ 
\cmidrule{3-4}
Clinic & Care & No & Yes  \\
\midrule
A & Less & 3& 176  \\ 
&More & 4 & 293  \\ \addlinespace
B & Less & 17 & 197 \\ 
& More & 2 & 23 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 

\end{center}
\end{table}


Tables \ref{marginalcountcs1} and \ref{marginalcountca1} are the marginal counts of the cliques $[CS]$ and $[CA]$ respectively.

\begin{table}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
            \caption{Marginal count of clique $[CS]$}
             \label{marginalcountcs1}
            \begin{tabular}{@{} lcc @{}}
                \toprule
                & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Survival}\\ 
                Clinic  & No & Yes  \\
                \midrule
                A & 7& 469  \\ 
                B & 19 & 220 \\
                \bottomrule

            \end{tabular} 
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
        \caption{Marginal count of clique $[CA]$} 
        \label{marginalcountca1}
        \begin{tabular}{@{} lcc @{}}
                \toprule
                & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Care}\\ 
                \cmidrule{2-3}
                Clinic  & Less & More \\
                \midrule
                A & 179 & 297  \\ 
                B & 214 & 25 \\
                \bottomrule

            \end{tabular} 
    \end{minipage} 
\end{table}

Now, the first step of the algorithm is setting the ML estimates to 1 for all the cells in the contingency table. This can be seen in Table \ref{tab:IPF1}.enter code here
```

However, the tables end up grouping like this.
[image]

I've tried using numerous letters such as [h], [ht], [b] after \begin{table} however these havent worked.

Comment: Please make your code compilable. (See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))

Comment: If you absolutely do not want your tables to float, drop the `table` environment, add the `caption` package and replace `\caption` with `\captionof{table}`.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue itself, but if you want to improve the alignment of the two side-by-side tables, you could use `\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}` for both of them. I'd also add a `\cmidrule{2-3}` to the left table just as you did in the right one

Comment: Instead of showing us a layout you do *not" want, please do tell us more about the layout you do wish to achieve.

Comment: @leandriis is it still possible to reference the table doing this, as it no longer has "Table 4.2"

Comment: Yes, referencig is definitely possible. Regarding: " it no longer has "Table 4.2" " What exactly did you try?

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{center} 
\begin{tabular}{@{} llcc @{}} 
\toprule 
& & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Survival}\\ 
\cmidrule{3-4} 
Clinic & Care & No & Yes \\ 
\midrule A & Less & 3& 176 \\ 
&More & 4 & 293 \\ \addlinespace 
B & Less & 17 & 197 \\ 
& More & 2 & 23 \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\captionof{table}{\label{tab:IPF1} The observed number of counts of the infant survival data} \end{center}

\ref{tab:IPF1}
\end{document}` should work.

Comment: you are already using `[H]` which makes the table not float so what else do you need??? Note however tables floating is a feature not a problem to be solved. It is in fact the only reason to use the `table` environment,